# Show upcoming dates in order based on current date jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am trying to get the current date and then order dates with the closest date div first.

I have managed to get the current date and format it but I am unsure of how to do the ordering?

Here's my attempt but it doesn't seem to order them or anything

```
<div id="dates">
  <div class="date"><span>10 September 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>22 July 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>29 August 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>28 July 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>5 August 2016</span></div>
</div>

var current = new Date();
console.log(current);

var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var elems = $.makeArray($(".date"));

var d = current.getDate();
var m =  months[current.getMonth()];
var y = current.getFullYear();

var formattedDate = d + " " + m + " " + y;

console.log(formattedDate);

elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return formattedDate > elems.text() );
});

$("#dates").html(elems);
```

Thanks

Comment: could you have dates in the past too, or only future dates?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you require it would be far easier to convert the values to dates and compare to the current date. From there you can `sort()` the `.date` elements and `append()` them to their container, like this:

```js
var now = new Date();
$(".date").sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDiff = new Date($(a).text().trim()) - now;
  var bDiff = new Date($(b).text().trim()) - now;
  return aDiff < bDiff ? -1 : aDiff > bDiff ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('#dates').filter(function() {
  return new Date($(this).text().trim()) - now < 0;
}).appendTo('#dates');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dates">
  <div class="date"><span>10 September 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>22 July 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>29 August 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>28 July 2016</span></div>
  <div class="date"><span>5 August 2016</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to get textContent of each `.date` and then set the html of `#dates`. now you are trying to acces `data("date")`. you changed the structure i see

Comment: Hi, is there a way to make the dates that have passed at the end of the upcoming dates so 28 July, 5 August, 29 Sept, 10 Sept, 22 July, cause I still need to keep the past dates but just have them at the end..

Comment: @eltonkamami I used the code from the OPs fiddle which appears different to the code in the question itself. Answer updated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Hi, is there a way to make the dates that have passed at the end of the upcoming dates so 28 July, 5 August, 29 Sept, 10 Sept, 22 July, cause I still need to keep the past dates but just have them at the end..

Comment: You could do that with an additional `filter()` to find passed dates, see my update for more details

Answer (score 0):

> closest date based on current date

```js
var element = $.makeArray($(".date"));
var array = [];
var current = new Date();

element.sort(function(a,b){
  var c = new Date($(a).text());
  var d = new Date($(b).text());
 
  return c-d;
});
for(var i in element){
   var d  = new Date($(element[i]).text());
  if(d >= current){
       $("#sorted").append(element[i])  
    } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dates">
  <div id="10 September 2016" class="date"><span>10 September 2016</span></div>
  <div id="22 July 2016" class="date"><span>22 July 2016</span></div>
  <div id="29 August 2016" class="date"><span>29 August 2016</span></div>
  <div id="28 July 2016" class="date"><span>28 July 2016</span></div>
  <div id="5 August 2016" class="date"><span>5 August 2016</span></div>
</div>
<h1>after sort</h1>
<div id="sorted"></div>
```